# How to read body content of latest email using jmeter?

Tags: datetime, email, jmeter

I am trying to read first email's body content to extract dynamic value "1234" from statement "This is 1234 hello"

I am using email reader sampler with config as: 
Number of messages to retrieve: 1

But in listener I see it shows body of last email on the page.

Please help. Further I would like to identify the same using timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

With JMeter's [Mail Reader Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mail_Reader_Sampler) as of [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) you have 2 options:

1. Retrieve **messages**
2. Retrieve **last N messages**

If you want to read the very first message in your inbox (the oldest one) you will have to go for your own implementation using:

- [Java Mail API](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/)
- [JSR223 Sampler with Groovy as the language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Example code which reads the first message from [Gmail](https://www.google.com/gmail/) via [IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) would be something like:

```
props.setProperty('mail.transport.protocol', 'imaps')
props.setProperty('mail.imap.host', 'imap.gmail.com')
props.setProperty('mail.imap.port', '995')
props.setProperty('mail.imap.ssl.enable', 'true');

def session = javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null)
store = session.getStore('imaps')
store.connect('imap.gmail.com', 'your_username@gmail.com', 'your_password')
inbox = store.getFolder('INBOX')
inbox.open(javax.mail.Folder.READ_ONLY)
def message = inbox.getMessage(1)
return message.getContent()
```

Comment: Hi @dimtri , how can I read the latest email?